# Fastest way to remove all users from an Azure AD group with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, group-membership

What is the fastest way to remove all users from an Azure AD group in PowerShell?
I am currently using

```
$deleteThem = Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $groupId -All 
foreach ($user in $deleteThem) {
    Remove-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $groupId -GroupMemberObjectId $user.ObjectId
}
```

but this is painfully slow.
I need to retain the group and group id though.
Any ideas?

Comment: I think there aren't many other ways than what you're doing right now. The AzureAD module _might be_ faster since its newer but can't tell for sure.

Comment: Maybe `Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $groupId -All | Remove-MsolGroupMember -GroupMemberObjectId $_.ObjectID`?

Comment: Use [Remove-AzADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/remove-azadgroupmember?view=azps-6.2.1), because `MemberObjectID` accepts an array. `$Users = Get-AzADGroupMember -GroupObjectID <some_id>; Remove-AzADGroupMember -GroupDisplayName <name_of_group> -MemberObjectId $Users.Id`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Ash. Alas, it's only marginally faster (4min 5secs compared to 4min 30secs for ~1300 users). Guess I have to settle with it :)

Comment: I would imagine that all of these modules are built from AutoRest, and that they are just making a Microsoft Graph call and then the backend has to process all the changes. You could look at doing it via the Azure/Graph REST APIs yourself to see if there is any significant difference, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by **Ash** in comments section , Using Remove-AzADGroupMember is faster than Remove-MsolGroupMember.

I ran the below script for deleting users in a group by just providing the Group name.

```
Import-Module AzureAD
$Credential = Get-Credential
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential
$group=Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString 'Your Tenant Group Name' 
$users=Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $Group.ObjectId -All $true |where {$_.ObjectType -eq 'User'}
foreach($user in $users){
Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $Group.ObjectId -MemberId $user.objectId
}
```

[image]

**Note :** In credentials prompt box, provide the admin id of the tenant and password. If there are lot of users in the group then it is expected to take some time.